# Unable to display Axis title in google timeline chart

Tags: google-visualization

I have following code to display all the pool cars with engagement for a day. First thing I want is to display a fixed hAxis of 24 hours. And the axis title would be a plus. But as of now, it is displaying the time axis only till it has an engagement. And the title is not displaying at all. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
google.charts.load("current", {packages:["timeline"]});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
    var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
    var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Vehicle' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Name' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
    dataTable.addRows([
        [ 'SEDAN 10', 'Default Function', new Date(0,0,0,17,00,0), new Date(0,0,0,19,00,0) ],
        [ 'SEDAN 11', 'IDLE', new Date(0,0,0,0,0,0), new Date(0,0,0,0,0,0) ],
        [ 'SEDAN 12', 'IDLE', new Date(0,0,0,0,0,0), new Date(0,0,0,0,0,0) ],
        [ 'SEDAN 13', 'IDLE', new Date(0,0,0,0,0,0), new Date(0,0,0,0,0,0) ],
        [ 'SEDAN 14', 'IDLE', new Date(0,0,0,0,0,0), new Date(0,0,0,0,0,0) ] ]);

    var options = {
        hAxis: { title: 'Hours'},
        viewWindow: {min: 0, max: 24},
        ticks: [0, 6, 12, 18, 24]
        timeline: {colorByRowLabel: true},
        height: 800
    };


    chart.draw(dataTable, options);
}
```

Comment: the options simply aren't supported by the [timeline chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline#configuration-options)...

Comment: I had to manage it other way!

Comment: @AdityaAmit Submit the solution that worked for you. It will be helpful for others.